# How to add a basic animation to a component in vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am looking at the official vue docs for animation, and I am confused how to implement the following example from vues website

```
Vue.transition('fade', {
  css: false,
  enter: function (el, done) {
    // element is already inserted into the DOM
    // call done when animation finishes.
    $(el)
      .css('opacity', 0)
      .animate({ opacity: 1 }, 1000, done)
  },
  enterCancelled: function (el) {
    $(el).stop()
  },
  leave: function (el, done) {
    // same as enter
    $(el).animate({ opacity: 0 }, 1000, done)
  },
  leaveCancelled: function (el) {
    $(el).stop()
  }
})
```

into my vue root

```
var v_root = new Vue({
    delimiters: [ '[[', ']]' ],
    el: '#vue-job',
    data: {
        job_s: []
    },
    created() {
        url="http://{{ api_endpoint }}"
        fetch(url)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(body => {
}}
```

Do I need to add this to my components?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working Example:

```
  <transition
          v-bind:css="false"
          v-on:before-enter="beforeEnter"
          v-on:enter="enter"
          v-on:leave="leave"
    >
    <p v-if="show">hello</p>
   </transition>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/posva/khd2ur97/

**Another example:**
https://jsfiddle.net/ayo7fL4t/

**Fade component:**
https://jsfiddle.net/nehadhiman6/4dpr7kmu/5/

Comment: I would like to fade the ENTIRE component

Comment: i have added another fiddle i hope this helps!

Comment: I was playing with your fiddle and I saw that if I remove the button - the components do not fade in when the page loads.  How can I fade in the components when they load (rather than on button click)?

Comment: I want to use your example but remove the button click

Answer (score 1):

Without Button:

**Component:**

```
Vue.component('greeting', {
  template: '<h1>Welcome here!</h1>'
});
```

// create a new Vue instance a

```
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',

});
```

**Template**

```
<div id="app">
      <transition name="fade" appear mode="out-in">
        <greeting></greeting>
      </transition>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.fade-enter-active, .fade-leave-active {
  transition: opacity .95s;
}
.fade-enter, .fade-leave-to /* .fade-leave-active below version 2.1.8 */ {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Working Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/nehadhiman6/r52vp7ah/3/

i hope this meets your requirement. :)